# How to place a div inside a function that creates a div

Tags: functions, hooks

I am wondering how instead of having the menuTab div come after the bones_main_nav function html code that is outputted to have it injected inside of it I suppose.

I have the following function

```
// the main menu
function bones_main_nav() {
    // display the wp3 menu if available
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container' => false,                           // remove nav container
        'container_class' => 'menu clearfix',           // class of container (should you choose to use it)
        'menu' => __( 'The Main Menu', 'bonestheme' ),  // nav name
        'menu_class' => 'nav top-nav clearfix',         // adding custom nav class
        'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // where it's located in the theme
        'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
        'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
        'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
        'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
        'depth' => 0,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
        'fallback_cb' => 'bones_main_nav_fallback'      // fallback function
    ));
} /* end bones main nav */
```

and the following html/php

```
<nav role="navigation">
                        <?php bones_main_nav(); ?>
                        <div id="menuTab">
                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></a>d
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

**UPDATE**
the bones_main_nav function generates the following html, i have commented where I want the menutab div to go.

```
<div class="nav footer-nav clearfix">
<ul>
<li>home</li>
</ul>
<div id="menuTab"></div>**<!--THIS IS WHERE I WANT MENU TAB TO GO-->**
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand whay you mean by injected inside it, are you looking for `'menu_class' => 'nav top-nav clearfix menuTab', ` maybe?

Comment: @Wyck I added a better explanation in the update portion of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use that function and do that but I do not know anything about `bones_main_nav` . Using the default WordPress function  ( which the bones function is wrapping) will only output `<ul>...menu items... </ul>`, then a simple way is to just wrap it in your template file.

For example:

```
 $defaults = (array(
        'container' => false,                          
        'menu' => __( 'The Main Menu', 'bonestheme' ),  // nav name
        'menu_class' => 'nav top-nav clearfix',         // adding custom nav class
        'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // where it's located in the theme
        'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
        'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
        'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
        'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
        'depth' => 0,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
        'fallback_cb' => 'bones_main_nav_fallback'      // fallback function
        ));
```

And your template markup would be:

```
<div class="nav footer-nav clearfix">
<?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
<div id="menuTab"></div>**<!--THIS IS WHERE I WANT MENU TAB TO GO-->**
</div>
```

A more complicated way via code would be to use a [Menu Walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walker)